# prefetch request body failed on forward proxy for Apache HTTP Server mod_proxy

Tags: apache, proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy, httpserver

I am using Apache HTTP Server mod_proxy as a proxy server between my client and the server. I am able to connect to my proxy server from my client. And then client is able to establish the connection and send the data to the server. But on the middle, somewhere connection is getting lost and it is giving the below error:

```
(OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : proxy: prefetch request body failed to 10.131.x.x:80 (10.131.x.x) from 10.131.y.y ()
```

I have tried adding the keep alive and other properties but it did not resolve my issue.
Here is my httpd.config file changes:

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyVia On
   </IfModule>

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 10.131.x.x
    </Proxy>
```

Also added this variables:

```
 KeepAlive On
 MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
 KeepAliveTimeout 15
 Listen 8080
```

Please need to know if any one faced the same issue and resolved it.

Thanks,
Arindam.

Comment: Is this a forward or reverse proxy?.